# Is it possible to read and write to the uC registers via UART

Tags: microcontroller, register

I wonder if the microcontroller register can be accessed(R/W) via UART , given that the controller has a UART interface. I've been searching for a while but didn't find any examples. Looks like it's all done via I2C or SPI

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question literally, I'd say no you can't directly modify processor register via UART (except for the side effects that UART communication has). But that would be based on my assumptions and thus probably be a bad answer.

I think, you need to give us a little more information on what exactly you are asking and/or trying to accomplish and give more context. E.g. what specific microcontroller are we talking about? What do you mean when you say "register"? What outcome are you after?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not talking about a specific microcontroller, I'm trying to build a "universal" register reader that is able to communicate with the registers via UART(faster than I2C protocol?). Probably it's impossible. If so, is it because the UART structure cannot fit the register R/W mechanism or is it because the current registers (uC) are not designed to communicate in UART?